# Why my JPARepositoryImpl code is not called?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-boot

I have the following simple Spring Boot code. Why my JPARepositoryImpl code - JpaCustomerRepository is not called (I know by adding print statement..)?

I had @ComponentScan added in the main and controller. Please advise.

Thanks,

```
    @Entity
    public class Customer implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long id;

        @Column(nullable = false)
        private String product;

        @Column(nullable = false)
        private String charge;

        protected Customer() {
        }

        public Customer(String product) {
            this.product = product;
        }

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getProduct() {
            return this.product;
        }


        public String getCharge() {
            return this.charge;
        }}


    public interface CustomerRepository extends Repository<Customer, Long> {

            List<Customer> findAll();

        }

        @Repository
        class JpaCustomerRepository implements CustomerRepository {

            @PersistenceContext
            private EntityManager em;

            @Override
            public List<Customer> findAll() {
                TypedQuery<Customer> query = em.createQuery("select c from Customer c",
                        Customer.class);

                return query.getResultList();
            }


        }

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SampleDataJpaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleDataJpaApplication.class, args);
    }

}
@Controller
@ComponentScan
@RequestMapping("/customers")
public class SampleController {
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Autowired
    public SampleController(CustomerRepository customerRepository) {
        this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/list")
    public String list(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("customers", this.customerRepository.findAll());
        return "customers/list";
    }


}
```

But sample code (JpaCustomerRepository)  from book Spring Data did get called. What's the catch?

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    /**
     * Returns the identifier of the entity.
     * 
     * @return the id
     */
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /* 
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {

        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }

        if (this.id == null || obj == null || !(this.getClass().equals(obj.getClass()))) {
            return false;
        }

        AbstractEntity that = (AbstractEntity) obj;

        return this.id.equals(that.getId());
    }

    /* 
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id == null ? 0 : id.hashCode();
    }
}
    @Entity
    public class Customer extends AbstractEntity {

        private String firstname, lastname;

        @Column(unique = true)
        private EmailAddress emailAddress;

        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
        @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
        private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<Address>();

        /**
         * Creates a new {@link Customer} from the given firstname and lastname.
         * 
         * @param firstname must not be {@literal null} or empty.
         * @param lastname must not be {@literal null} or empty.
         */
        public Customer(String firstname, String lastname) {

            Assert.hasText(firstname);
            Assert.hasText(lastname);

            this.firstname = firstname;
            this.lastname = lastname;
        }

        protected Customer() {

        }

        /**
         * Adds the given {@link Address} to the {@link Customer}.
         * 
         * @param address must not be {@literal null}.
         */
        public void add(Address address) {

            Assert.notNull(address);
            this.addresses.add(address);
        }

        /**
         * Returns the firstname of the {@link Customer}.
         * 
         * @return
         */
        public String getFirstname() {
            return firstname;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the lastname of the {@link Customer}.
         * 
         * @return
         */
        public String getLastname() {
            return lastname;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the lastname of the {@link Customer}.
         * 
         * @param lastname
         */
        public void setLastname(String lastname) {
            this.lastname = lastname;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the {@link EmailAddress} of the {@link Customer}.
         * 
         * @return
         */
        public EmailAddress getEmailAddress() {
            return emailAddress;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the {@link Customer}'s {@link EmailAddress}.
         * 
         * @param emailAddress must not be {@literal null}.
         */
        public void setEmailAddress(EmailAddress emailAddress) {
            this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
        }

        /**
         * Return the {@link Customer}'s addresses.
         * 
         * @return
         */
        public Set<Address> getAddresses() {
            return Collections.unmodifiableSet(addresses);
        }
    }
    public interface CustomerRepository extends Repository<Customer, Long> {

        /**
         * Returns the {@link Customer} with the given identifier.
         * 
         * @param id the id to search for.
         * @return
         */
        Customer findOne(Long id);

        /**
         * Saves the given {@link Customer}.
         * 
         * @param customer the {@link Customer} to search for.
         * @return
         */
        Customer save(Customer customer);

        /**
         * Returns the customer with the given {@link EmailAddress}.
         * 
         * @param emailAddress the {@link EmailAddress} to search for.
         * @return
         */
        Customer findByEmailAddress(EmailAddress emailAddress);
    }
    @Repository
    class JpaCustomerRepository implements CustomerRepository {

        @PersistenceContext
        private EntityManager em;

        /* 
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * @see com.oreilly.springdata.jpa.core.CustomerRepository#findOne(java.lang.Long)
         */
        @Override
        public Customer findOne(Long id) {
            return em.find(Customer.class, id);
        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * @see com.oreilly.springdata.jpa.core.CustomerRepository#save(com.oreilly.springdata.jpa.core.Customer)
         */
        public Customer save(Customer customer) {
            if (customer.getId() == null) {
                em.persist(customer);
                return customer;
            } else {
                return em.merge(customer);
            }
        }

        /* 
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * @see com.oreilly.springdata.jpa.core.CustomerRepository#findByEmailAddress(com.oreilly.springdata.jpa.core.EmailAddress)
         */
        @Override
        public Customer findByEmailAddress(EmailAddress emailAddress) {
            TypedQuery<Customer> query = em.createQuery("select c from Customer c where c.emailAddress = :email",
                    Customer.class);
            query.setParameter("email", emailAddress);

            return query.getSingleResult();
        }
    }
```

Original code test method,

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = PlainJpaConfig.class)
public class JpaCustomerRepositoryIntegrationTest extends AbstractIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    CustomerRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void insertsNewCustomerCorrectly() {

        Customer customer = new Customer("Alicia", "Keys");
        customer = repository.save(customer);

        assertThat(customer.getId(), is(notNullValue()));
    }

    @Test
    public void updatesCustomerCorrectly() {

        Customer dave = repository.findByFirstname("Dave");
        assertThat(dave, is(notNullValue()));

        dave.setLastname("Miller");
        dave = repository.save(dave);

        Customer reference = repository.findByFirstname(dave.getFirstname());
        assertThat(reference.getLastname(), is(dave.getLastname()));
    }
}
```

My main method code,

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = PlainJpaConfig.class)
public class SampleDataJpaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleDataJpaApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I have extra @EnableAutoConfiguration which the original code doesn't have? Could this be the reason? But without @EnableAutoConfiguration, I can't start Spring Boot Container.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not called because Spring Data is dynamically supplying the implementation for CustomerRepository. Your code is redundant (in a sense that it is not doing something that Spring Data cannot do automatically) but in case you want to see how you can augment the implementation supplied by Spring Data with code that it could not have generated automatically, check out the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.custom-implementations).

Comment: But sample code (JpaCustomerRepository) from book Spring Data did get called. What's the catch? See my original post.

Comment: My best guess is that in the original code, Spring Data is not configured to automatically supply the implementation for the repository, whereas in your code, Spring Boot automatically configures Spring Data for this feature. Can you post the configuration of the book code?

Comment: There isn't much configuration in Spring data other than these annotations. I have extra EnableAutoConfiguration which the original code doesn't have? Could this be the reason? But without  EnableAutoConfiguration, I can't start Spring Boot Container. I've updated the code in my original post.

Comment: As I said @EnableAutoConfiguration (from Spring Boot) among other this makes Spring Data dynamically supply an implementation for the repository. The original code does not use Spring Boot which means that it might not configure Spring Data